# xamarin.ios architecture conditional compilation

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I need to compile Xamarin.iOS projects for all three architectures, ARM7, ARM7s and ARM64. As ARM7s gets obsolete, some components do not link, and in the way to make gracefull degradation, I need to have different code for ARM7s and normal devices, all within one ipa package

Is something like this possible?

```
#if __ARM7s__
//gracefull degradation
#endif
```

Comment: Why do you need to build ARMv7s? To submit an app to the App Store, Apple only requires ARMv7 and ARM64 architectures, and soon they will only allow ARM64.

Comment: App that is built without ARM7s have problems installing on iPhone 5 and 5C, ones that built on ARM7s

Comment: Interesting- what problems are you experiencing on the 5 and 5C?